# But the sizeof() operator doesn't work on pointer but works on the array name. Why is it so?

Tags: c, pointers

Hi i was doing this exercise and wanted to get the size of array after i pass the pointer to the array to the function:

But the sizeof() operator doesn't work on pointer but works on the array name. Why is it so? 
Is this any way i could get the size of the array on the findPut function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//global vars
int i,j;
//functions prototypes
void findPut(int *, int);

int main(void){
    int ins=4;
    int arr[10]={1,2,3,5,6,7,8};
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(arr));     //gives 40
    int *ap=arr;
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(*ap));     //gives 4 instead of 40 why?? if ap and arr the same thing


    findPut(ap, ins);
    return 0;
}

//functions
void findPut(int *p, int n){
    //vars
    //getting size of array
    int size= sizeof(*p);   
    //sizeof(int);
    printf("%d\n",size);        //gives 4 but expected 40????

}
```

Comment: Because arrays and pointers are not same! Do you expect apples and oranges to taste the same?

Answer (score 3):

When you dereference `*p` you get an `int`, so it returns 4 (which is the size of `int` on your platform).

Comment: `sizeof (int)` is *not* always 4.  This answer needs clarification or it *will* cause confusion.  `p` is a pointer to an integer, `*p` is an integer, and `sizeof *p` is the size of an integer, which on the OPs platform is 4.

Comment: Agreed! My answer has been edited.

Answer (score 3):

Because, `sizeof(*ap)` means `sizeof(arr[0]);` since array is of type `int`, `sizeof(int)`, **since in your system configuration**, `int` is of size `4` you got the result as `4`.

You can try it your self by printing the value of `*p`, you will get the value of `arr[0]`.

Let `int *p` be a pointer and `int arr[10]`

Please note that:

1. `Arrays` and Pointers are **not equivalent**.
2. `sizeof` operator is a compile time operator.
3. `sizeof(arr)`, evaluates to `10*sizeof(int)`, that is `10*4=40` in your case.
4. When you dereference p (getting the value that p points to), it doesn't give you whole array, but one unit of 
   your array that is an `int` so, `*p` means `arr[0]`. `sizeof(arr[0])` is 
   4 (in your case) that's obvious.
5. When you use `sizeof(p)`, it will give you the size of the pointer in your machine. 
   In my machine it is 8.
6. `main` function's return type should be `int` always. It has to retport operating system the exit status of the program. If you use `void` it might return random garbage.

The example demonstrate the issue:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
  int *p=NULL;
  int arr[10]={10,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  p=arr;
  printf("values: arr[0]=%d  *p= %d\n\n",arr[0],*p);
  printf("sizes : sizeof(arr[0])=%lu, sizeof(*p)= %lu sizeof(int)=%lu\n\n",sizeof(arr[0]),sizeof(*p),sizeof(int));
  printf("Sizeof pointer p: %lu \n\n",sizeof(p));
  printf("Sizeof arr: %lu \n\n",sizeof(arr));

  printf("Pointing p to the first byte of 100 byte sequence\n\n");
  p=malloc(100);

  printf("Though p is pointing 100 byte block, sizeof(p)=%lu",sizeof(p));
  return 0;
}
```

Essentially, `sizeof` evaluates the `sizeof type` but not the `sizeof type` it points to.

> Thank you, i do appreciate your knowledge but is there any way i could
>   find the size of array inside another function( not the one where i
>   define the array).

You can't in my IMHO! You have to pass the size along with the array.

Example:

```
 int main(){
   int arr[10]={10,1,2,3,4,5};
   printf("Length of array: %lu",findLength(arr,sizeof(arr)));
   return 0;
 }
 size_t findLength(int *p,int size){
    return size/sizeof(*p);
 }
```

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior: `%d` doesn't match with `size_t`. You must use `%zu`.

Comment: @Jens thanks :) but %zu is not working.... you meant %u? typo?

Comment: No, %zu is the format introduced by C99 to print a size_t. Are you using a C89 implementation, like MS Visual Studio? Then you should use `printf ("%lu", (unsigned long)sizeof(foo))`. Remember, size_t is defined to be an unsigned type.

Comment: @Jens I'm using devcpp, which uses gcc. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an `int` array and an `int` pointer:

```
int arr[10] = {1,2,3,5,6,7,8};
int* ap;
ap = arr;
```

In C, the expression **`arr` is equivalent to `&arr[0]`**. It stands to reason, then, that **`*ap` is equivalent to `arr[0]`**, which is an `int`, which for your binary has a size of 4.

You also need to understand that **arrays and pointers aren't the same thing**. You may have been confused by the fact that arrays and pointers are often used interchangeably in the sense that a pointer can store the address of the beginning of an array (its first element, in other words) and navigate the consecutive addresses as if it had the actual array passed to it.